# Cannot access expansion file deployed with app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, apk-expansion-files

I have an AS3/AIR application for deploying on Google Play. The app has an expansion file attached to it. The expansion file is named "main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myapp12.obb" and it is downloaded along with the app properly.

The problem is I cannot access the expansion file any way I tried, like:

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('Android/obb/main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myapp12.obb');
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('/Android/obb/main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myapp12.obb');
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myapp12.obb');
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('/main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myapp12.obb');
```

and similar variations. I cannot access the file even when the path while developing on Windows seems to be right. When deployed, I just got the "not found" error in my catch block with the supplied File url property: "app-storage:/Android/obb/main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myapp12.obb" . I have been looking for the solution and trying various approaches for several days, but I am stuck. Developed on ASUS EEE PAD.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var path : String = "Android/obb/air.com.mycompany.myappli";
var filename : String = "main.1000000.air.com.mycompany.myappli.obb";
var file : File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(path + "/" + filename);
if (file.exists)
{ ... }
```

Hope this help